# Why does JTextfield not show up in this instance?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm new to Java and still trying to wrap my head around GUIS and events that being said why does why does the the text field not show in this instance (only shows the circle)...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JDemoOval extends JFrame 
{
static JTextField text;
double x = Math.random()*100;
double y = Math.random()*100;

int xfinal = (int)x;
int yfinal = (int)y;
public void paint(Graphics tool)
{
  super.paint(tool);
  tool.drawOval(50, 50, xfinal, xfinal);
  calcBox();
  
}
public void calcBox() {
   
   int rad = xfinal/2;
   double rad2 = (double)rad;
   double cir = 2*Math.PI*rad2;
   double area = Math.pow(Math.PI,2);
   int dia = xfinal;
   
   text = new JTextField(20);
      
   text.setText("Hello");

}
}
```

Comment: Where to you add the text field to the frame? Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for a working demon. The `TextDemo` shows how to properly create a simple class.  Also, you painting code is wrong. The tutorial also has a section on `Custom Painting`.

Comment: Had a feeling my whole approach was wrong, but will do  appreciate the advice